# Equivalence of the norms $N_{\alpha}(f)=\int_{0}^{\alpha}|f(t)| d t+\sup _{t \in[\alpha, 1]}|f(t)|$

Tags: functional-analysis

On $E=\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ and for $\alpha\in[0,1]$ we define the norms $$N_{\alpha}(f)=\int_{0}^{\alpha}|f(t)| d t+\sup _{t \in[\alpha, 1]}|f(t)|$$

1. compare $N_\alpha$ and $N_\beta$.
2. Are $N_\alpha$ and $N_\beta$ equivalents?

My attempt : I could show that if $\alpha<\beta$ then $N_\beta(f)\leq(1+\beta-\alpha) N_{\alpha}(f)$, In fact
$$\begin{aligned}
N_{\beta} \left( f\right) &=\int_{0}^{\beta}|f| d t+\sup _{[\beta, 1]} |f| \\
&=\int_{0}^{\alpha}|f| d t+\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}|f| d t+\sup _{[\beta, 1]} |f| \\
& \leqslant \int_{0}^{\alpha}|f| d t+(\beta-\alpha) \sup _{[\alpha,\beta]} |f|+\sup _{[\beta, 1]} |f| \\
& \leqslant \int_{0}^{\alpha}|f| d t+(\beta-\alpha) \sup _{[\alpha, 1]}|f|+\sup _{[\alpha, 1]}|f| \\
&=\int_{0}^{\alpha}|f| d t+(1+\beta-\alpha) \operatorname{sup}_{[\alpha, 1]}|f| \\
& \leqslant(1+\beta-\alpha) \int_{0}^{\alpha}|f| d t+(1+\beta-\alpha) \sup _{[\alpha, 1]}|f| \\
&=(1+\beta-\alpha) N_{\alpha}(f)
\end{aligned}$$

I feel like those two norms are not equivalants. but I can't find a sequence $(f_n)$ to prove it

Comment: Try to make up a function $f$ that is mostly equal to $0$ but has a triangular "spike" where it reaches $1$, wholly contained in the strip $\alpha\le x\le\beta$. That will make $N_\alpha(f)=1$. Now, make the width of the spike tend to $0$ to get $\int_0^\beta |f(t)|dt$ tend to $0$ too.

Comment: E.g. let the graph of $f_n(t)$ be the polygonal line joining points $(0,0), (\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}-\frac{1}{n}, 0), (\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}, 1), (\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}+\frac{1}{n}, 0), (1,0)$ for large enough $n$ ($n>\frac{2}{\beta-\alpha}$), and $\alpha<\beta$.

Comment: okey , I'll try that . thaks you !!!

Answer (score 1):

[[image: The graph of <span class=]$(f_n)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4wsy.png)

Thanks to @stinking Bishop.

We have $$\begin{aligned}
&N_{\alpha}\left(f_{n}\right)=\int_{0}^{\alpha}\left|f_{n}\right| d t+\sup _{[\alpha ,1]}\left|f_{n}\right|=0+1=1 \\
&N_{\beta}\left(f_{n}\right)=\int_{0}^{\beta}\left|f_{n}\right| d t+\operatorname{sup}_{\left[\beta ,1\right]}\left|f_{n}\right|=\frac{1}{n}+0=\frac{1}{n}
\end{aligned}$$

Hence we get $$\lim _{n \rightarrow+\infty} \frac{N_{\alpha}\left(f_{n}\right)}{N_{\beta}\left(f_{n}\right)}=\infty$$ which shows that the two norms can't be equivalents.